# Проблемы с VPN соединением на Mikrotik, почему падает соединение?

Tags: vpn, mikrotik

Все доброго времени суток. 
В общем купил себе роутер Mikrotik map lite чтобы пробросить туннель до домашнее роутера по EoIP.
Дома на роутере Zyxel поднял VPN сервер и начал подключается к нему с mikrotik-а по PPPtP(интернет на mikrotik настроен как свитч ) и получается такая ситуация mikrotik подключается к vpn серверу после чего начинает падать основное интернет соединение из-за чего соответственно падает vpn-клиент после чего поднимается интернет соединение и все по новой!

Comment: так дефолт сменился

Comment: @eri , что делать то ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо добавить маршрут до VPN в микротик. Zyxel добавляет его автоматически.

Например, адрес впн сервера 1.2.3.4. В настройках pptp клиента поставь дистанцию 50. В подключении интернет дистанцию 60 (дхчп-клиент). И добавляешь маршрут target=1.2.3.4 с дистанцией 40 через шлюз интернета.

Либо не использовать дефолт в впнах.